# Illegal Argument Exception using Random Forest in PySpark mllib

Tags: pyspark, random-forest, apache-spark-mllib, illegalargumentexception

I am using Random Forest algorithm for classification in Spark MLlib using PySpark. My codes are as follows:\

```
model = RandomForest.trainClassifier(trnData, numClasses=3, categoricalFeaturesInfo={}, numTrees=3, featureSubsetStrategy="auto", impurity='gini', maxDepth=4, maxBins=32)

predictions = model.predict(tst_dataRDD.map(lambda x: x.features))

labelsAndPredictions = tst_dataRDD.map(lambda lp: lp.label).zip(predictions)

testErr = labelsAndPredictions.filter(lambda x: x[0] != x[1]).count() / float(tst_dataRDD.count())
```

I got **IllegalArgumentException**: GiniAggregator given label -0.0625but requires label to be non-negative.
How can I solve this problem? Thanks

Comment: full stacktrace please?

Answer (score 1):

It seems for `Gini` impurity during multiclass classification, the labels must be positive (>=0). Please check if there are any negative labels present.

ref - [spark repo](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/tree/impurity/Gini.scala#L97)

Also, on side note, please use algorithm from `ml` package and not from legacy `mllib`

Answer (score 0):

Please use `RandomForestClassifier` instead and see the docs:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-classification-regression.html#random-forest-classifier